# Console of Dev Tools in Excel for Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, office-js

I have built an add-in which works fine in Excel online, whereas it does not work in Excel 2016 for Windows.

I know that in Windows 10, we could use [this tool](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) to debug the add-in, however I am using Windows 7.

I just installed Visual Studio 2017, right clicking on the add-in shows a menu where `Attach Debugger` is. But clicking on `Attach Debugger` fires nothing.

Does anyone know how to debug in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two potential options:

You can use [Volorn.js](http://www.vorlonjs.com/) to remotely debug your add-in. You can use the [Debug Office Add-ins on iPad and Mac](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac) article as a starting point. Although this article is targeting Mac and iPad, the concepts are the same for Windows.

You can also use Visual Studio by creating a new Excel Web Add-in. Simply replace the default manifest with your own. Note that you still need to retain the default web site, Visual Studio still this for some library references. It will use your manifest's URL for the source location however.

Answer (score 1):

Office applications use Internet Explorer for the web browser, so all settings from IE should carry over. I have found that if you disable (uncheck) both the `Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)` and `Disable script debugging (Other)` options, your debugger breakpoints will be hit (I tested this in Outlook 2016).

You will need add [`debugger;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statements to the source code to add breakpoints. When these statements are hit, a dialog like this should appear: [image: debugger popup]

Simply select 'Yes' and a new instance of visual studio should open, with the debugger attached to your script.